# A session variable doesn't get passed properly?

Tags: php, variables, session, superglobals

So, I am trying to set a $_SESSION variable and pass it to another page, but the variable on the other page is different than the one it must be.

In `petitionlist.php` the `$_SESSION['petitionNameT'] = $petitionName1;` is being set.
The contest of `$petitionName1` is different depending on which page you choose to click and it shows properly in the url id.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $petitionName1 = $row['petitionName'];
    $_SESSION['petitionNameT'] = $petitionName1;
    echo "<tr><td><a href='petition.php?id=$petitionName1'>";
    echo $row['petitionName'];
    echo "</a></td><td>";
    echo $row['petitionTheme'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

But when we go on `petition.php` the result displayed is very different than the one that should be and it's the exact same for every page, no matter on which one you clicked.

```
    <?php
    $petitionNameT = $_SESSION['petitionNameT'];
    ?>
    
    <div id="wrapper">
    
        <div id="contents">
    
            <h1 class="headers"><?php echo $petitionNameT?></h1>
            
            <p>
            
            </p>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

**FOR AN EXAMPLE:**

On the first page clicked it should be `petitionTest`, but it is `petitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetiti`

On the second page clicked it should be petitionTest2, but it is `petitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetiti`

And so on and so on

**P.S.**
`petitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetitionNameTestpetiti` is the name of one of the pages that can be clicked.

**P.S.(2)**
I just found out that it takes the name of the last page possible to be clicked from the database.

Comment: Is your second PS the solution, I can't tell? You seem to be mixing session with query string. In your loop you are overwriting the session each time, with, as you noticed, the last row holding the session value. When a user clicks, you want to inspect the query string to see what they clicked. You could then, if you really wanted to, set the session value to that, although if you can avoid dealing with sessions in the first place, your live will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code `$_SESSION['petitionNameT']` is overwritten each iteration of the loop so it will always be `petitionName` from the LAST row in the query.

You probably don't want a session.  Just use the `id` that you are including in the query string of the links:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr><td><a href='petition.php?id={$row['petitionName']}'>";
    echo $row['petitionName'];
    echo "</a></td><td>";
    echo $row['petitionTheme'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Then in `petition.php`:

```
$petitionNameT = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: You are a god among men! Thank you from my heart and soul